# Make Event by addEventListener When Click On Image does not work

Tags: javascript, html, events, click, addeventlistener

In Javascript , I am trying to make event when click on img. i use addEventListener.

my code what do ? : there are six images in my page.
and every image has two classes. the first class is 'img-class' and all the images have it.

and the second class is 'id' word and number. for example :
the second class of image one is 'id1' , and the second class of image two is 'id2'.

what i want to do : i want when i click on any image from the six image the console print the second id of the image which i clicked.

the problem is 'no thing happen when i click on the image , no print error in the console no thing happen' .

i tried to get the second class without click event and work.

so the problem in event function.

where is the problem ?

this is javascript code :

```
var Img_Img = document.querySelectorAll('.img-class');

    Img_Img.forEach(Img_Img_Img => {
    
        Img_Img_Img.addEventListener("click" , ()=>{
            if (Img_Img_Img.classList.contains("imgimg") != null) {
                Img_Img_Img.classList.remove("imgimg");
            }
        
            if (Img_Img_Img.classList.contains("imgimg") == null) {
                Img_Img_Img.classList.add("imgimg");
            }
    
    
            document.querySelectorAll('.imgimg').forEach( imgimgimg => {
                var idid = imgimgimg.getAttribute('class').split(' ')[1];
                console.log(idid);
                
            });
    
            });
    });
```

html code :

```
  <div class = "images-images">
                <div>
                        <img src = "Images/watch.jpg" class = "img-class id1">
                    <div class = "overlay-image-image"></div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <img src = "Images/watch_2.jpg" class = "img-class id2">
                    <div class = "overlay-image-image"></div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <img src = "Images/card.jpg" class = "img-class id3">
                    <div class = "overlay-image-image"></div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <img src = "Images/shoes.jpg" class = "img-class id4">
                    <div class = "overlay-image-image"></div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <img src = "Images/card_2.jpg" class = "img-class id5">
                    <div class = "overlay-image-image"></div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <img src = "Images/headphones.jpg" class = "img-class id6">
                    <div class = "overlay-image-image"></div>
                </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: You might want to check for typos in your code. 
You should use the .includes method, .contains does not exist in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substring method to get only part of a string.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.img-class');

images.forEach(function (image) {image.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(image.className.substring(10, 13)))})
```

```html
    <div class = "images-images">
        <div>
                <img src = "Images/watch.jpg" class = "img-class id1">
            <div class = "overlay-image-image"></div>
               <div>
                    <img src = "Images/watch_2.jpg" class = "img-class id2">
                    <div class = "overlay-image-image"></div>
                </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Img_Img_Img.classList.contains() method always return boolean value. So your code should be follows.

```
if (Img_Img_Img.classList.contains("imgimg") == false) {
    Img_Img_Img.classList.add("imgimg");             
}
```